# Rails 3.1 and dynamic jquery ui-theme switch

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

To be brief:

application.css

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require vendor
*/
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .
```

and vendor/assets$ tree

```
.
└── stylesheets
    ├── ui-themes
    │   ├── smoothness
    │   │   ├── images
    │   │   │   ├── ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png
    │   │   │   ├── ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png
    │   │   │   ├── ui-bg_glass_55_fbf9ee_1x400.png
    │   │   │   ├── ui-bg_glass_65_ffffff_1x400.png
    │   │   │   ├── ui-bg_glass_75_dadada_1x400.png
    │   │   │   ├── ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png
    │   │   │   ├── ui-bg_glass_95_fef1ec_1x400.png
    │   │   │   ├── ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png
    │   │   │   ├── ui-icons_222222_256x240.png
    │   │   │   ├── ui-icons_2e83ff_256x240.png
    │   │   │   ├── ui-icons_454545_256x240.png
    │   │   │   ├── ui-icons_888888_256x240.png
    │   │   │   └── ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png
    │   │   └── jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css
    │   └── trontastic
    │       ├── images
    │       │   ├── ui-bg_diagonals-small_50_262626_40x40.png
    │       │   ├── ui-bg_flat_0_303030_40x100.png
    │       │   ├── ui-bg_flat_0_4c4c4c_40x100.png
    │       │   ├── ui-bg_glass_40_0a0a0a_1x400.png
    │       │   ├── ui-bg_glass_55_f1fbe5_1x400.png
    │       │   ├── ui-bg_glass_60_000000_1x400.png
    │       │   ├── ui-bg_gloss-wave_55_000000_500x100.png
    │       │   ├── ui-bg_gloss-wave_85_9fda58_500x100.png
    │       │   ├── ui-bg_gloss-wave_95_f6ecd5_500x100.png
    │       │   ├── ui-icons_000000_256x240.png
    │       │   ├── ui-icons_1f1f1f_256x240.png
    │       │   ├── ui-icons_9fda58_256x240.png
    │       │   ├── ui-icons_b8ec79_256x240.png
    │       │   ├── ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png
    │       │   └── ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png
    │       └── jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css
    └── vendor.css.erb
```

Then my problem is how to dynamic load jquery theme css through params[:theme], i tried

```
/*
*= require "ui-themes/<%= params[:theme] %>/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom"
*
*/
```

in vendor.css.erb, but not lucky.

thanks for any help.

Comment: you don't have access to any dynamic parameters etc in your assets, because usually they're precompiled and not compiled for every request (for obvious performance reasons). this would make any dynamic data stale. so jquery-ui theme switching could be quite an effort.

Comment: assets pipeline sounds good but frustrated me much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. solution, include all possible themes in your css file, but scope them, i.e. nest all rules under a distinct body id (or class) e.g.
   `#theme-1 ui-widget-... { .. }`
   etc...
   then switch the id of your body tag dynamically
2. solution make an own css for every theme (each also including your other styles), add those files to `config.assets.precompile` in your `config/environments/production.rb`, disable the hash cache buster suffix (there is a question here at stack overflow how to do this) and then switch stylesheets on your server side (in your layout) by param

Comment: i just realized, you don't have to disable the cache buster hash

Comment: I just created a sample rails application which demonstrates and explains the handling of multiple jquery-ui themes, see: https://github.com/fpauser/rails-with-multiple-jquery-ui-themes